# Consulta LINQ com somatório

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Tenho a seguinte consulta em LINQ

```
var dados = _db.Contratos
    .Where(a => a.Adesoes.Any(b => b.Pago))
    .Select(a => new
    {
        Contrato = a.Numero,
        ValorTASenior = a.Adesoes.Where(b => b.Pago).Sum(b => b.ValorTASenior),
        ValorTAMaster = a.Adesoes.Where(b => b.Pago).Sum(b => b.ValorTAMaster),
        ValorTAConsultor = a.Adesoes.Where(b => b.Pago).Sum(b => b.ValorTAConsultor),
        ValorCliente = a.Adesoes.Where(b => b.Pago).Sum(b => b.ValorCliente)
    });
```

Gostaria de saber de que forma posso simplificar os somatórios dos valores e evitar o `a.Adesoes.Where(b => b.Pago)` para cada somatório que preciso fazer.

Entidades & Contexto

```
public class MeuContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contrato> Contratos { get; set; }
}

public class Contrato
{
    [Key]
    public int ContratoId { get; set; }

    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Adesao> Adesoes { get; set; }
}

public class Adesao
{
    [Key]
    public int AdesaoId { get; set; }
    public int ContratoId { get; set; }
    public bool Pago { get; set; }
    public int ValorTASenior { get; set; }
    public int ValorTAMaster { get; set; }
    public int ValorTAConsultor { get; set; }
    public int ValorCliente { get; set; }
    public virtual Contrato Contrato { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: você não já esta fazendo isso no seu primeiro where ? .Where(a => a.Adesoes.Any(b => b.Pago))

Comment: Sim, mas gostaria de evitar repetir esse Where para cada somatório.

Comment: acho que saquei o senário. o seu problema esta no seu any ... seu where se satisfaz com a primeira Adesão que temo Pago = true...  você precisar que sua select receba todas as Adesoes que foram pagas assim você não precisa do filtro dentro do select.

Comment: O meu Any garante que só retorno os contratos que tenham adesões na situação de pagas, mas mesmo assim alguns contratos podem ter adesões pagas e não pagas. Então por isso faço o Where no select para somar só as adesões pagas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode criar um select com o seu filtro antes do select final. 
Como você comentou não vou alterar seu where, mas a solução seria assim.

```
var dados = _db.Contratos
    .Where(a => a.Adesoes.Any(b => b.Pago))

    .Select(a => new
    {
        Contrato = a.Numero,
        Adesoes = a.Adesoes.Where(b => b.Pago),
    })
    .Select(a => new
    {
        Contrato = a.Contrato,
        ValorTASenior = a.Adesoes.Sum(b => b.ValorTASenior),
        ValorTAMaster = a.Adesoes.Sum(b => b.ValorTAMaster),
        ValorTAConsultor = a.Adesoes.Sum(b => b.ValorTAConsultor),
        ValorCliente = a.Adesoes.Sum(b => b.ValorCliente)
    });
```

Comment: Muito bem, era algo do tipo que imaginei fazer. Obrigado

Comment: Sabe dizer se isto é eficiente, ou detona a performance do SQL?

Comment: @Maniero tenho essa dúvida também. Vou ver como fica o desempenho disso ai.

Comment: @Maniero, enquanto for AsQueryable a query esta sendo montada, como ele monta, vai demandar de como o modelo é criado. dependendo ele poder criar um subselect ou fazer um join retornado apenas os campo que estão no select.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza é exatamente isso que eu questiono, alguma coisa me diz que o SQL gerado com isto deve ser bem ruim. Quando o Pablo comentou, eu pensei em pega a coleção para filtrar, ia fazer teste antes porque eu acho que ficaria bem ruim, mas aí você respondeu e eu desisti.

Comment: @Maniero, da forma que esta a performance será bem melhor que da forma que ele montou na pergunta,  praticamente ele esta criando um subselect para cada campo do select que tem um SUM. uma forma de contorna isso seria usar o groupby, mas precisaria saber o contexto do que seria retornado na query para ter ideia do que fazer melhor.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Pensei no `GroupBy` ou até em algum `Join`. Mas odeio todas essas coisas, já não sou fã de SQL, uma abstração em cima dela é pior ainda.

Comment: O SQL gerado, fazendo group by, ficou com 178 linhas e o SQL usando a forma da reposta do @MarconcilioSouza ficou com 105 linhas. usando a solução da resposta o tempo de execução mostrado pelo MiniProfile é de 204ms, usando com group by fica em torno de 150ms.

Comment: é nem sempre o sql gerado é uma coisa bonita de ser ver, o linq ajuda muito na construção rápida de uma aplicação. mas se você precisar mesmo de performance um O/RM bom mesmo é o Dapper. dependendo de sua aplicação você pode combinar os dois o/rm e usar o dapper onde precisar de uma performance maior.   Mas se for usar mesmo o EF use da forma que seja mais facil e que der uma performance aceitável para sua aplicação.  como o group by você tem ganhos e por traz você não vai ver mesmo o código então não tem que se preocupar com isso deixe o EF se vira com isso

Comment: Vou adicionar como resposta a opção com Group By

Comment: Legal. é bom ter mais referencia de como fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Outra possibilidade é começar a consulta pela entidade Adesão já filtrada pelas pagas, juntamente com um *group by*.

```
var dados = _db.Adesoes
    .Where(b => b.Pago)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Contrato)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        Contrato = a.Key.Numero,
        ValorTASenior = a.Sum(b => b.ValorTASenior),
        ValorTAMaster = a.Sum(b => b.ValorTAMaster),
        ValorTAConsultor = a.Sum(b => b.ValorTAConsultor),
        ValorCliente = a.Sum(b => b.ValorCliente)
    });
```

A resposta do @MarconcilioSouza gera um SQL menor, no entanto o tempo mostrado [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/) é um pouco maior do que usando *Group By*.

Usando o *Group By* tenho como tempo de execução em torno de 150ms e usando conforme a resposta do @MarconcilioSouza, tenho em torno de 200ms.

Comment: Você não tentou fazer o group by apenas pela propriedade Numero ?

Comment: Vou fazer essa alteração é ver como fica